# trying to make a multi language app, issue with httpclient

Tags: angularjs, ngx-translate

Hi I tried [this tutorial](https://www.gajotres.net/ionic-2-internationalize-and-localize-your-app-with-angular-2/2/) and when I add this

```
import {HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {TranslateModule, TranslateLoader} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient ) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

I am getting this type of error

```
Argument of type 'HttpClient' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Http'. Property '_backend' is missing in type 'HttpClient'.
```

What should I do to fix this error